# ASP.NET Core project returns wrong localization after being idle

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, localization, asp.net-core-localization

My localization works fine but if the site is idle for about 15 minutes then the next page load always returns english. So I load a page and the language is correct, leave it for 15 mins and refresh and it is english. A second refresh or changing page fixes it until left idle again.

This happens both when developing locally and running with visual studio and when deployed on IIS on server. I have tried to hunt down all standby/hibernate settings etc. from the server just to be sure but that didn't work.

I have checked that the culture cookie is set correctly and is being sent with every page load.

Localization is done as described in the asp.net core documentation.

Any idea what this could be related to?

EDIT:

To be clear, I'm mostly using View Localization.

Like this:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization

@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer

<h2>@ViewData["Title"].</h2>
```

In the Startup.cs I have these:

```
services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

services.AddMvc()
            .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
            .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();

services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
        {
            CultureInfo[] supportedCultures = new[]
            {
                new CultureInfo("fi-FI"),
                new CultureInfo("en-US")   // Even if I comment this line, the problem still occurs
            };

            options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "fi-FI", uiCulture: "fi-FI");
            // Formatting numbers, dates, etc.
            options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
            // UI strings that we have localized.
            options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;

        });
```

And in the Configure method:

```
IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions> locOptions = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
        app.UseRequestLocalization(locOptions.Value);
```

And in the controller this is what I use to let users change the language.

```
public IActionResult SetLanguage(string culture, string returnUrl)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Setting language to " + culture);
        Response.Cookies.Append(
            CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
            CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(culture)),
            new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(1) }
        );

        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
    }
```

And this works. Except for the behavior described. So I can't be far off if there is something wrong. I hope :D

Thanks for anyone who takes time to think about this!

Comment: Check the cookie expiration time on your browser, how long is it?

Comment: `Localization is done as described in the asp.net core documentation.` Please show us that code.

Comment: It is set to one year.

Comment: I added some code.